# How to rename subfolders by numerical pattern and order based on theirs parent in python

Tags: python

I have a folder with many sub-folders, and each sub-folder also has two sub-folders. The structure looks like this:

```
--folder
  --sub-f1
   --1-1000
   --1-1050
  --sub-f2
   --1-1030
   --1-1060
  --sub-f3
   --1-1040
   --1-1070
```

What I want to achieve is extract the folder with smaller number in name(in the above example, 1-1000, 1-1030 and 1-1040) and rename these folders according to their parent folders(sub-f1-1, sub-f2-1 and sub-f3-1). I'm running Windows 10 and any simple solutions are welcome!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience, I will try to do better next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a fairly verbose algorithm to explain step by step how it works:

```py
from glob import glob
import os

root_dir = 'folder'  # specify here your root dir, in your example is "folder"
parent_dirs = glob(f"{root_dir}/*", recursive=True)  # detect all first level subdirs

for parent in parent_dirs:
    # for each parent dirs, detect all childs
    child_dirs = glob(f"{parent}/*", recursive=True)
    
    # for each child, extract the last part of name (e.g. 1000) and append to list
    child_nums = []
    for child in child_dirs:
        child_nums.append(child.split(os.sep)[-1].split("-")[-1])
    
    # find smallest child num and its index in list to retrieve corrispondent full path
    small_child = min(child_nums)
    small_child_index = child_nums.index(small_child)

    src_folder = child_dirs[small_child_index]
    
    # compose the destination dir name 
    dst_folder = os.path.join(parent, parent.split(os.sep)[1] + "-1")

    os.rename(src_folder, dst_folder)
    print(f"src_folder '{src_folder}' renamed as: '{dst_folder}'")
```

output will be:

```
src_folder 'folder\sub-f1\1-1000' renamed as: 'folder\sub-f1\sub-f1-1'
src_folder 'folder\sub-f2\1-1030' renamed as: 'folder\sub-f2\sub-f2-1'
src_folder 'folder\sub-f3\1-1040' renamed as: 'folder\sub-f3\sub-f3-1'
```

This solution can be implemented in many other ways, even without using glob and just using `os.walk()` for example. You can use much more optimized algorithms but it depends on how many folders you need to rename. This is just a simple example.

Comment: Just tried it out, this solution works a charm! Thanks for the inspiring answer, and it will definitely help me get better at Python!